# C#.NET - How can I get typeof() to work with inheritance?

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, typeof

**I will start by explaining my scenario in code:**

```
public class A { }

public class B : A { }

public class C : B { }

public class D { }

public class Test
{
    private A a = new A ( ) ;
    private B b = new B ( ) ;
    private C c = new C ( ) ;
    private D d = new D ( ) ;

    public Test ( )
    {
        // Evaluates to "false"
        if ( a.GetType == typeof(B) ) { } //TODO: Add Logic

        // Evaluates to "true"
        if ( b.GetType == typeof(B) ) { } //TODO: Add Logic

        // I WANT this to evaluate to "true"
        if ( c.GetType == typeof(B) ) { } //TODO: Add Logic

        // Evaluates to "false"
        if ( d.GetType == typeof(B) ) { } //TODO: Add Logic
    }
}
```

**The important line to take notice of here is:**

```
if ( c.GetType == typeof(B) ) { }
```

I believe that this will in fact evaluate to "false", since typeof(B) and typeof(C) are not equal to each other in both directions. (C is a B, but B is not necessarily a C.)

But what I need is some kind of condition that will take this into account. How can I tell if an object is a B or anything derived from it?

I don't care if it is an object DERIVED from B, so long as the base B class is there. And I can't anticipate what derived class might show up in my application. I just have to assume that unkown derived classes may exist in the future - and therefore I can only focus on making sure that the base class is what I am expecting.

I need a condition that will perform this check for me. How can this be accomplished?

Comment: You should avoid this kind of logic where possible.  When you have to determine what the derived type of an object is, you're not making good use of polymorphism.

Comment: See my comment on Steven Sudit's answer.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can just use `is`:

```
if (c is B) // Will be true

if (d is B) // Will be false
```

Comment: As a response to the only actual question in the OP: "How can I tell if an object is a B or anything derived from it?" this is the correct answer. Mine is the answer to the thread title, but less appropriate for the described problem.

Comment: Ah, true enough. You are correct, my question is a bit fuddled there. My bad.

Answer (score 28):

Edit: this answers the question in the thread title. [cdm9002](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218178/c-net-how-can-i-get-typeof-to-work-with-inheritance/1218194#1218194) has the better answer to the problem as described in the full post.

```
typeof(B).IsAssignableFrom(c.GetType())
```

Comment: The answer from cdm9002 is better, since it doesn't use reflection.

Comment: @pb: If you want to get technical, the other answer doesn't use `typeof` with inheritance. As you can see from my edit, I'm not one to claim the first answer I thought of is the most appropriate. :)

Comment: This is not only a perfectly correct answer, but also in addition covers the case when you do not have instances of any of the the classes at hand, but still want to determine whether there is an inheritance relationship between two types.

Answer (score 5):

This looks like a job for polymorphism, as opposed to a big switch statement with tests for specific classes.

Comment: Indeed. Put a virtual method on class A, override as appropriate in subclasses, then call this virtual method.

Comment: How rude!! Haha. My class logic doesn't actually look like this mess. I just needed to figure out how to perform this condition. I'm writing a PropertyChangedCallback method IN the abstract base class, and I need a security condition that will ensure that the DependencyObject parameter is an object derived from my base class. If not, I throw an error or cancel my logic. Polymorphism isn't helpful in this instance.

Comment: Ok, then using "is" should suffice.

Answer (score 1):

```
typeof(B).IsInstanceOfType(c)
```

Similar to the answer above from sam-harwell, sometimes you may have the type "B" in a variable, so you need to use reflection rather than the "is" operator.

I used Sam's solution, and was pleasantly surprised when Resharper made this suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

For VB.NET with Visual Studio 2008, you can check it like:

```
'MyTextBox control is inherited by Textbox
If Ctl.GetType.Name = "MyTextBox" then    

End If
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the `(c is B)` check, you can also do the following:

```
var maybeB = c as B;
if (maybeB != null) {
   // make use of maybeB
}
```

This is preferred in some cases since in order to make use of `c` as a `B` when using `is`, you would have to cast anyway.